# Celery: How to get the task completed time from AsyncResult

Tags: python, celery

I need to trace the status for the tasks. i could get the 'state', 'info' attribute from the AsyncResult obj. however, it looks there's no way to get the 'done_date'. I use MySQL as result backend so i could find the `date_done` column in the `taskmeta` table, but how could i get the task done date directly from AysncResult obj? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the `_cache` object of the AsyncResult after you have called `res.result`

for example

`res._cache['date_done']`

Comment: Note that this is an implementation variable (what most OOPLs name "private") so expect you code to possibly break with any new celery release.

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. i would apply this solution temporarily :).